# BigQuery error: Encountered " "WHERE" "WHERE ""

Tags: google-bigquery

I just tried to run the following in BigQuery:

```
SELECT *
WHERE repository_owner = 'facebook' AND repository_name = 'react'
FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline]
LIMIT 1000
```

but received the error:

> Error: Encountered " "WHERE" "WHERE "" at line 2, column 1. Was expecting:

What does the error mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This error pops up if the `WHERE` clause is in the wrong place. Changing the query to

```
SELECT *
FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline]
WHERE repository_owner = 'facebook' AND repository_name = 'react'
LIMIT 1000
```

fixes the problem.